# How to fix the #DIV/0 when asking for 2 sums then dividing them?

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is the formula I am using im trying to add 3 cells then divide by the totale of another 3 but I get the div/0. Im trying to get a percentage.
=SUM(F7+F55)/SUM(E7+E55)

Comment: A [`#DIV/0!`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Correct-a-DIV-0-error-ef9c486d-2fcd-40e6-829d-f36b4d7068b0) means it can not divide by `0`. Does one of those `SUM` formulas result in `0`? What research have you done to correct this?

Comment: Is your intent to only sum `F7` with `F55`? OR are you wanting to sum `F7` ***thru*** `F55`?

Comment: Just curious why you are using the SUM function here.  The + signs do the math.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sum is resulting in a zero, which you are then dividing by. The obvious fix would be to ensure that you have more then zero in the cells that are part of the second sum.

Your formula as typed above is not referencing a range. It is actually adding the values in two cells, and then doing a sum on that single value.  Using E7:E55 in place of E7+E55 would fix this issue.

I'm assuming this is not the issue, then I think it is ***IF*** to the rescue!

Here is a link to Microsoft's help page on the topic:

> https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

In your case a protective formula may look like this:

```
=IF(sum(E7:E55)=0,"Zero Sum",SUM(F7:F55)/SUM(E7:E55))
```

Which reads as: If the sum of the range E7:E55 is a zero, then display the message "Zero Sum", otherwise perform the division as usual.

Comment: Please don't make the assumption the OP wants to add more than `E7+E55` which is what you are suggesting with `E7:E55`. Before being able to give a solid answer, you might want to get clarification from the OP.

Comment: Fair enough. This is, of course, why I gave both answers.

Answer (score 1):

Divide by 0 (possible SUM result) will bring the error #DIV/0!.
Excel (from 2007) has the function [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) to catch such possible cases:

`=IFERROR((F7+F55)/(E7+E55),0)`

The second Parameter (0) is the value you got, wenn an error (#N/A, #VALUE!, #REF!, #DIV/0!, #NUM!, #NAME?, or #NULL!) occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try =SUM(F7:F55)/SUM(E7:E55)

I assume you're trying to sum two columns.

The other possibility you could mean I suppose is

=F7+F55/E7+E55

However the notation as currently used in the question makes no sense.

Comment: That is a far leap to make that assumption. It is better to ask for clarification than to post a assumptive answer.

Comment: Edited then @CharlieRB

Comment: Just write  =If((E7+E55)>0, (F7+F55)/(E7+E55),"The sum is Zero")     or whatever remarks you want